# How to close a window opened using browser.windows.create()?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I cannot find any questions/answers that address this issue. Sorry if I have missed something.

I am just getting started with WebExtensions. I have a form that is displayed in a window that I open in my *background.js* script using `windows.create();`. I cannot figure out how to close that window (other than manually clicking the close box). The window is created and correctly displays my form. I can even submit the form. But I cannot get the window to close. I have even tried injecting a content script into the form page - I cannot close it from there either. I have tried attaching a handler to the `click` event of a button, with no luck.

It is my understanding that only the script that creates the window can close it. But I cannot figure out, or find by searching online, how I would do that in my `browserAction` background script (which is where the window is created)?

I am running Firefox 51 on Debian.

Here is the code that creates the window.

*background.js*

```js
var formUrl = 'http://example.com/api/test'
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(
  function(tab)
  {
    chrome.tabs.query({"active": true, "currentWindow": true}, function(tabs) 
      { 
      var target = tabs[0].url;
      if (target.substr(0,4) == 'http')
      {
        var encUrl = escape(target);
        var newUrl = formUrl + '?default=' + encUrl;
        w = chrome.windows.create({
          url: newUrl,
          width: 775,
          height: 350,
          type: 'popup'
        });
      }
      else
      {
        console.log("Only http(s) pages can be processed at this time.");
      }
    });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API call [`windows.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/remove) is specifically for closing a window. You will need the `windowId`, which is available as the [`id` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/Window#Type) within the [`windows.Window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/Window) Object which is passed to the callback/resolve function for [`windows.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/create).

You do not need to call `windows.remove()` from the same script which opened the window. Any script with access to that API can close the window.

Comment: thanks for the response. i guess i had missed the whole "Promise" thing. I now have access to the window id in my background script, but not in the script loaded into the form in the newly opened window (part of the webextension). what i want to do is close that window when a button in the window's form is clicked, so i want to attach a handler to the onclick of that button. i am not at all clear on how to do that - where do i have access to both the form elements AND the window id?

Comment: @Laz: Short answer: By design, nowhere; you have to use [messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Communicating_with_background_scripts). (continued)

Comment: @Laz: All scripts in the background share the same context, but not the same scope. This means that, after obtaining a reference to their scope, you can directly call functions/access variables/access the DOM/etc. for any of your popup or tabs that are displaying extension pages, options pages, the background page/scripts from any other of those. So, the answer to where you have access to the window ID and can call the `windows` API is: from anywhere in the background context. (continued)

Comment: @Laz: However, your "popup" appears to actually be a window displaying a tab that is a content page. Programmatically, this is nearly identical to a normal browser window displaying a tab, it just looks different. You're opening a remote page into which, I assume, you inject a content script (not shown in the question). That script will be running in a content script context, not the background.(continued)

Comment: @Laz: You will need to [send a message](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Communicating_with_background_scripts) from that content script to the background page requesting the popup be closed.Obviously, you could also send a message with the window ID to the content script, but the content script does not have access to the `windows` API, thus can not close the window. So the answer to your question is: By design, there is nowhere that both has access to a content page's DOM and has access to the `chrome.windows` API needed to close the window.

Comment: thanks much, makyen. yes, my window is a real window (of type 'popup'). i guess the messaging is what i need to brush up on, i have not dealt with that yet at all. i will take a look at that. i appreciate your help!

Comment: thanks again makyen, i did get this working pretty easily once i grokked the messaging paradigm. i inject a content script into relevant pages, and message between that and the background script. works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a window created by an extension in Firefox from a "dismiss" button this way:

```
GetEl('dismiss').addEventListener('click',function(e)
    {
    browser.windows.getCurrent().then(F2);
    });
function F2(info)
    {
    return browser.windows.remove(info.id);
    } // F2
```

(GetEl returns the element node for a given id string.)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let popupWindowId = null; // Variable to store the popup window ID

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  let data = JSON.parse(request);

  chrome.windows.create(
    {
      url: 'popup.html',
      type: 'popup',
      focused: true,
      top: data.top,
      left: data.left - 500,
      width: 400,
      height: 550
    },
    (window) => {
      popupWindowId = window.id; // Store the ID of the created popup window
    }
  );
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (message === 'popupClose') {
    if (popupWindowId) {
      chrome.windows.remove(popupWindowId); // Close the popup window using its ID
      popupWindowId = null; // Reset the popup window ID
    }
  }
});
```

In your background.ts file define a variable and assign it to null initially
then the window you are creating, assign the window.id of it inside of the callback for the popupWindowId
and after that add onMessage listner with a specific name, and call remove on the window id :)